# PHP text replace? ( endings )

Tags: php, string, text

original string: `$text = "aaaa aaaasomething someaaaa aaaa 89aaaa aaaathis"`

final result i need: `$textresult = "aaaa aaaasomething some4a aaaa 894a aaaathis"`

I mean: I want to replace any string on the text that ends with aaaa to 4a. But only if it is an ending and not an isolated string like aaaa or a string that starts with aaaa.

I presume str_replace or preg_replace could eventually do this in a single code line but do not have idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if a word is `fooaaaaa` -> should it become `fooa4a` or not match at all?

Comment: i see... yes it should match so the solution u gave works!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$textresult = preg_replace('/\Baaaa\b/', '4a', $text);
```

`\B` only matches between two alphanumeric characters, i. e. in the middle of a word.

`\b` only matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, i. e. at the start or end of a word.